# What is the meaning of the definition below? Taken from a 1909 book on Integral Equations.

Tags: integral-equations

Definition:
We say that the discontinuities of a function of $(x, y)$ are regularly distributed in $S$ or in $T$ if they all lie on a finite number of curves with continuously turning tangents, no one of which is met by a line parallel to the axis of $x$ or of $y$ in more than a finite number of points.
1.  Some Preliminary Propositions and Definitions.

In order to avoid interruptions in later sections, we collect here certain propositions of the integral calculus for future reference.
We shall have to deal with functions of one and of two variables.
The independent variables, which we will for the present denote by
x and (x, y) respectively, are in all cases real. In fact, in order to
avoid unnecessary complications we will assume that, unless the
contrary is explicitly stated, all quantities we have to deal with are
real.
The range of values of the single argument x is usually

I      a <= x <= b.

We shall speak of this in future simply as the interval.
In the case of functions of two variables, two cases have to be
considered. Interpreting (x, y) as rectangular coordinates in a plane,
we sometimes consider the square:

S      a <= x <= b & a <= y<= b

and sometimes the triangle

T      a<=y<=x<=b

It should be noticed that the three regions we have just defined,
I, S, T, are closed regions, that is they include the points of their
boundaries.

In order to avoid long circumlocutions we lay down the following:
We say that the discontinuities of a function of (x, y) are regularly distributed in S or in T if they all lie on a finite number of curves with continuously turning tangents, no one of which is met by a line parallel to the axis of x or of y in more than a finite number of points.

In order to make the enunciation of some of our results simpler,
we will assume once for all that the functions we deal with are defined
even at the points of discontinuity, at least in the cases where they
remain finite in the neighbourhood of such points.
The following theorem will be important for us. We state it first
for the case of the region S.

THEOREM 1.

If the two functions f(x, y) and g(x, y) are finite in
S and their discontinuities, if they have any, are regularly distributed
the function 
            b
F(x,y) = INT (f(x,v)g(v,y)dv
            a
is continuous throughout S.

The truth of this theorem becomes evident if we interpret (x,y,v)
as rectangular coordinates in space. It is then clear that the function
under the integral sign is finite throughout the cube

a <= x <= b, a <= y<= b, a <=v <= b,

and becomes discontinuous in this cube only at points on two sets of
cylinders whose generators are parallel respectively to the axes of x and
y. Moreover these cylinders are so shaped that any line x = xo, y = yo
in this cube meets them at only a finite number of points. The formal
proof, based on these or similar considerations, presents no difficulty,
and we leave it for the reader.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of the page? Maybe with the context around it... (I'm not saying I could help, but that $S$/$T$ thing looks ill-defined if you don't add context and perhaps others could help you better if you did show the page.)

Comment: I have added some before and after paragraphs. The book is Introduction to Integral Equations by Maxime Bocher. It is available on the Internet Archive.

Comment: What part of the definition do you not understand?

Comment: This bit: no one of which is met by a line parallel to the axis of x  or of y  in more than a finite number of points. Does he mean these lines meet the tangents or the curves and when they do, what do these meetings signify?

Comment: How does his definition relate to the requirement that for a function to be integrable it has to be continuous and differentiable? I assume if the curve has 'continuously turning tangents' he means that it is differentiable? Where do the horizontal and vertical lines meeting the tangents come in?

Comment: This is more general. Continuous and differentiable imply integrability, but there are discontinuous functions that are integrable. The author here is making a rather awkward assumption that all discontinuities lie on some continuously differentiable curves that only meet each horizontal and vertical line finitely many times. That means that Fubini's theorem will only encounter finitely many discontinuities on each slice, so the slices will integrate.